# Select div by data attribute with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In my `each()` I would like to:

1. hide all divs where the `data-infos.grpid = $jQuery(this).data('infos').grpid`
2. show the next div where `data-infos.ordre = $jQuery(this).data('infos').next_ordre`

I don't know how to make a "where" with the data attribute and do a 'hide' or 'show' on it.

```js
jQuery("div[testid]:visible").each(function() { 
    //Hide all div with same data-infos grpid
    //display the next one with 'next_ordre' (ordre=2 in this example)
});
```

```html
<div testid="afcnG0tN" data-infos='{"banid":"3cxWET0T", "grpid":"12c0RNPo", "ordre":"1", "next_ordre":"2"}'>Test 1</div>
<div testid="afcnG0tN" data-infos='{"banid":"0i9fIbei", "grpid":"12c0RNPo", "ordre":"2", "next_ordre":"3"}' style="display: none">Test 2</div>
<div testid="afcnG0tN" data-infos='{"banid":"pTgfUFLf", "grpid":"12c0RNPo", "ordre":"3", "next_ordre":"1"}' style="display: none">Test 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery("div[testid]:visible").each(function() { 
    var $that = $(this),
        data = $that.data('infos'),
        hideDivs = getTargetDiv('grpid', data.grpid),
        showDivs = getTargetDiv('ordre', data.next_ordre);

    hideDivs.forEach(function($div) {
        $div.hide();
    });

    showDivs.forEach(function($div) {
        $div.show();
    });
});

// Select some divs that pass the given check
function getTargetDiv (key, value) {
    var results = [];
    $('[data-infos]').each(function () {
        var $that = $(this),
            data = $that.data('infos');

        if(data[key] == value) results.push($that);
    });

    return results;
}
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/fxzhfvoz/

---

Another way:

```
jQuery("div[testid]:visible").each(function() { 
    var $that = $(this),
        data = $that.data('infos');

    doActionOnTargetDiv('grpid', data.grpid, 'hide');
    doActionOnTargetDiv('ordre', data.next_ordre, 'show')
});

function doActionOnTargetDiv (key, value, action) {
    $('[data-infos]').each(function () {
        var $that = $(this),
            data = $that.data('infos');

        if(data[key] == value) {
            if(action === 'hide') {
                $that.hide()
            } else if(action === 'show') {
                $that.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm just surprise that we must make a foreach and not a "select" like : jQuery("div[testid]").data('infos').where('ordre','2').show();

Answer (score 1):

here is my code to hide

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div[testid]:visible").each(function() {  
        if($(this).attr('testid') ===  $(this).data('infos').grpid){
            $(this).hide();
        }        
    }); 
});
```

let me know if that helps, here you can check the attribute === data value, you can do the same for other check. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you first define a data structure with initial information to be met:

```
var dataInfos = {
        grpid = "12345",
        ordre = "2"
    },
    nextOrdre;
```

Then you would iterate to find which one to hide and then iterate to show the other one that corresponds to the next_ordre:

```
$("div[testid]:visible").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        infos = $this.data("infos");
    if (infos.grpid === dataInfos.grpid) {
        $this.hide();
        nextOrdre = infos.next_ordre;
    }
}

if (nextOrdre) {
    $("div[testid]").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            infos = $this.data("infos");
        if (infos.ordre === nextOrdre) {
            $this.show();
        }
    }
}
```